# Calculate percentage between values inserted in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one table contain all the emails that i sent to some people, and the other table contains all the people who registred in my website after i sent them those emails.

What i need to achieve is to calculate the percent fo the users that registred, so for now i have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from email_sent       //10   
SELECT COUNT(*) from registred_users  //2
```

For this example i need to build a query witch will return 20% because 2 out of 10 means 20%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    mailsSent 
    , userAmount 
    , CONVERT(decimal(14,2), mailsSent) / CONVERT(decimal(14,2), userAmount) AS Percentage
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS mailsSent from email_sent) a
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) AS userAmount from registred_users) b
```

Basically the two subqueries will get you your original values in the form of 2 aliased columns, which you can then divide from the main query.

Edit:

An alternative to the explicit conversion is multiplying with 1.0 to turn the value into numeric. As stated in my comment, only 1 conversion is actually necessary:

```
SELECT 
    mailsSent 
    , userAmount 
    , mailsSent  * 1.0 / userAmount AS Percentage
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS mailsSent from email_sent) a
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) AS userAmount from registred_users) b
```

Comment: @paulalexandru Please see the edited query. Basically we convert both values to decimal (only the second one is necessary, but I prefer being consistent) and then do the division. I also aliased the column for you :)

Comment: Please go through my answer as well. [Here's my answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7eb98/1). I just created sample tables.